# Beginner circuit multimeter reads strange current

Tags: led, resistors, multimeter, breadboard, circuits

I have constructed the following very simple circuit.

[image]

I would like to measure the current running through the circuit with my multimeter. I break the circuit as follows and connect the red lead to the jack that says 10A max. I turn the dial to 10 amps.

[image]

When I connect the multimeter, I am reading -0.01 amps or -10 milliamps.

[image]

The following simulation screenshot shows that I would expect to get 65 milliamps.

[image: simulation]
What am I doing wrong here for there to be a difference between my multimeter and the simulator?

EDIT:

Here is the result using the 200m setting. I am unable to get the led to light up and the multimeter reads 0.0

[image]

Comment: In your simulator you have 9V while in the first picture you have 5V.But what confuses is a 55mA difference in current  with 4V difference in voltage is very small.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust that meter, honestly. It's from a brand I don't recognise, and looks rather cheaply constructed. I wouldn't be surprised if it's out by 5 ULP.

Comment: @MissMulan Would that cause the difference here? Also would I expect to see 10 mA in this case?

Comment: @s_kirkiles what is the knee voltage of the LED?

Comment: @MissMulan looking at the data sheet it seems to be 1.8 volts

Comment: @s_kirkiles if you run the simulator with a 5V source which is the result of the simulation?

Comment: @MissMulan I get 28.5 mA. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: You have a 200mA setting on DMM.  Use that.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat When I use the 200mA setting nothing happens. Is that to be expected or does this indicate a blown fuse? I have updated the question with an image of what happened.

Comment: What does the multimeter read for the supply voltage? How do you know what the supply voltage is? Are you using a voltage regulator? If your supply voltage is correct, but the multimeter reads something different, well, that is your problem. Maybe new batteries would help.

Comment: It reads so messed up on the 10A scale because you're measuring something that's 1000x smaller than the max reading, so the meters acting a little wonky down there.   Using the 200mA scale is correct, but you've blown a fuse in the meter (or it's defective).  Alternate --- put a 1 ohm resistor in your board where you're putting the meter terminals.  It'll hardly affect this circuit.  Then switch your meter to "volts".   Because it's a 1 ohm resistor, you'll get VOLTS = AMPS  (really...  Check ohms law it's true)    So if you measure 10mV across the 1 ohm resistor, it means there's 10mA there.

Comment: @KyleB Could I use a 10 ohm resistor and do the same thing?

Comment: The picture showing your 200mA measurement has the red probe connected to the Volts input on the multimeter. Move that into the current input, and measure again.

Comment: @YellowYeti: The 10A input is only for the 10A range.  The center input is labelled "Volts, Ohms, mA", and would be used for the 200 mA range - see the labelling in the second and third photos.

Answer (score 4):

Fix your 200mA scale blown fuse.   ( who hasn't blown their DMM fuse yet? hasn't done enough research )

I’m assuming you know which banana plug receptacles to use...for the 200mA scale...

To measure current accurately, verify R ohms then in the circuit, measure its voltage drop and apply Ohm's Law.

Comment: >>> Fix your 200mA scale blown fuse. ( who hasn't blown their DMM fuse yet? hasn't done enough research )       I bought a box of 100 fuses for our lab at work because EVERY FRIGGING TIME I'd pick up a meter that fuse would be blown!

Comment: Must be lots of R&D there eh?   I remember our female tech. at Burroughs in the early 80’s complaining about having to replace the 1pF FETs on the TEK. Diff probe.  Every previous engineer who used it blew one except me. With more than 25V poof, it didn’t  stand a chance with any finger charge.

Comment: Not so much R&D ... rather we are exceedingly generous taking on EE interns from the local colleges....   :/